# mercurial: figuring out which revision a file came from

Tags: mercurial

Given a file that came from some version of a repository, and may have since been modified, is there a good way to identify the version that it (most likely) came from? Something, I would expect, along the lines of comparing it to all the file's versions (or enough of them) and choosing the one with the smallest diff.

My use case: Over the years I have written and set loose various latex styles that are still in use. Much of the time there was no official "release" and no version number, and sometimes I forgot to update the version number. I now regularly get questions about this or that file. I'm using mercurial to keep track of the styles' history (some of them retroactively), and it would be handy to quickly find a script's place in history so I can tell if I'm dealing with a problem I fixed already.

I'm interested in how to match a file against repo history. The forward-looking solution is clear: avoid the problem by always using version numbers. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12486188/699305) to a related question suggests, the KeywordExtension could automate version numbers. Since its use is not recommended, I would also welcome suggestions for a "better" approach.

Comment: > Since its use is not recommended

Only by *some* opinions "not recommended", and it's opinion, not requirement

Comment: Agreed; but I respect the wisdom of the mercurial developers, so I'm open to hearing about alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use anything except checksums for file-in-question and it's historical revisions
2. You haven't any checksum-related keywords in Mercurial templater
3. You can add new commands to Mercurial, using [alias] section (and even shell-commands are allowed in alias definition)

The above leads to the conclusion that there are at least two solutions

- You can write extension for Mercurial, which add and implement template-keyword for checksuming, calculate checksum of external file, get checksums of all revisions of file (`hg log FILENAME --template "{md5(FILENAME)}\n"`) and will try to find hit
- You add alias to Mercurial for checksum, `log FILENAME` will give you all revisions for file, md5 -r REV FILENAME produce md5-based hashes again:

`hg log FILENAME --template "{rev}\n" | xargs $(...)`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for pinning down unmodified copies of past versions. Any ideas that might work with copies that have been modified? Perhaps I wasn't clear but that's the scenario I tried to describe. E.g., someone sends me mods, but I don't know to what...