# Find likely base revision in a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, diff

I received some code as a tar archive (without the `.hg` directory). I know which repository this code is based on, but not which revision was used as a base for these modifications. Is there some way to find this out by just looking at the files? This is similar to [Given a file, how to find out which revision in a mercurial repository this is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484224/given-a-file-how-to-find-out-which-revision-in-a-mercurial-repository-this-is) but I cannot reach the author of the code, so I cannot control how the files are extracted from the repository. I am also dealing with modified files here so the diff to the base revision would not be empty.

My fall-back plan would be to loop through all revisions and using the one with the smallest diff, but I'm still hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: **There are not** better solution. You can only try to diff single file at once and use diff | wc -l for bisecting per-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automated way to do it, but you could possibly reduce the time by using a `hg bisect --command  diff ...` command to zero in on it.

As a tip if you (I know it probably wasn't) you ever has to give someone a snapshot again, use `hg archive` to make it.  It includes a `.hg_archive.txt` file with version info that'll help if you have to do this again.

Comment: Bisect will **not** help (mea culpa), because with diff you'll not get single "bad-good" change, but "bad-good-bad" only

Comment: Yeah, you're right that you won't get good/bad, but if you output the revision and the number of lines of diff for each and then return 'bad' it'll work through all the revisions for you and then you can just look for the lowest.